# Почему нажимая на пустой список во фрагменте верхнего уровня, нажатия обрабатываются элементами интерфейса скрытого фрагмента нижнего уровня?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

Почему нажимая на пустой список во фрагменте верхнего уровня, нажатия обрабатываются элементами интерфейса скрытого фрагмента нижнего уровня?

ТО есть, у меня есть главное активити и несколько фрагментов. Из первого фрагмента может вызываться второй (через главное активити и замену фрагментов), в котором есть ListView. Если список не пуст, тогда всё нормально. Однако, если его очистить, то нажимая на пустое пространство во втором фрагменте вызываются события onClick() у элементов интерфейса не видимого в данный момент времени первого фрагмента. В чём дело? Или как этого избежать?

Comment: Вы можете приложить к вопросу ваш код?

Comment: Добавить атрибут `clickable="true"` к корневому элементу второго фрагмента.

Comment: Благодарю! Ваш совет помог.